# Loading the binary data to a NumPy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binary, numpy-ndarray

I am having trouble reading the binary file. I have a NumPy array as,

```
data = array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  7.821725  ],
              [ 0.05050505,  0.        ,  7.6358337 ],
              [ 0.1010101 ,  0.        ,  7.453858  ],
              ...,
              [ 4.8989897 ,  5.        , 16.63227   ],
              [ 4.949495  ,  5.        , 16.88153   ],
              [ 5.        ,  5.        , 17.130795  ]], dtype=float32)
```

I wrote this array to a file in binary format.

```
file = open('model_binary', 'wb')
data.tofile(file)
```

Now, I am unable to get back the data from the saved binary file. I tried using `numpy.fromfile()` but it didn't work out for me.

```
file = open('model_binary', 'rb')
data = np.fromfile(file)
```

When I printed the data I got `[0.00000000e+00 2.19335211e-13 8.33400000e+04 ... 2.04800049e+03 2.04800050e+03 5.25260241e+07]` which is absolutely not what I want.

I ran the following code to check what was in the file,

```
for line in file:
    print(line)
    break
```

I got the output as `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\......\c1\x07@\x00\x00\x00\x00S\xc5{@j\xfd\n'` which I suppose is in binary format.

I would like to get the array back from the binary file as it was saved. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use [np.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)?

Comment: @QuangHoang Actually, I have a very large file and hence I wish to save it in binary format.

Comment: You only need to specify the filename (or path) as argument when using ```data.tofile``` and ```np.fromfile```. But I am not sure why the python file object does not work. Maybe you are not closing the stream after doing the write?

Comment: You could also specify ```dtype=float32``` keyword when using ```np.fromfile```.

Comment: @SurajS `np.save` saves file to `.npy` which is binary.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you very much. I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin noted, adding the dtype is required. You might also need to reshape (you have 3 columns in your example. So

```
file = open('model_binary', 'rb')
data = fromfile(file, dtype=np.float32).reshape((-1,3))
```

should work for you.

As an aside, I think `np.save` **does** save to binary format, and should avoid these issues.

Comment: The dtype need to be ```np.float32``` I think.

Comment: You are correct - I was copy-pasting from the question.